# Doctrine MasterSlaveConnection with empty env-vars

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-dbal

```
# doctrine.yaml
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_MASTER_URL): ''
    env(DATABASE_SLAVE1_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MASTER_URL)%'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                slaves:
                    slave1:
                        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_MASTER_URL)%'
                        charset: utf8mb4
```

When i run `php bin/console cache:clear` i get this error:

`The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if no PDO instance is given to DriverManager::getConnection().`

This happens, when we do not have overwritten the env vars `DATABASE_MASTER_URL` & `DATABASE_SLAVE1_URL`.
In on step of our gitlab pipeline, where do not have those values at hand, we need to clear / warmup the cache.

The thing that is funny here: If i remove the definition for slaves, everything works fine. It only happens in a scenario where we define slaves.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION 1**
The WrapperClass "MasterSlaveConnection" does exactly what is need, but only to late. It takes the "driver" from the config and injects it into `master` and the `slave` nodes.

But this happens *AFTER* `DriverManager::parseDatabaseUrlScheme` is called.

So either
1) I am doing something wrong here and  there is room for improvement in documentation
or 
2) there is a bug

Comment: i have the same issue .   did you ever get any solution to this
ADDITIONALLY, this works fine on my local,   but crashes our CI server

Comment: I went with a different approach: 

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/2.6/configuration.html#line-number-8a4126f76f95d6cae9df49ff8bbe76da80b477ff-132

Comment: so you used 'replicas' instead of 'slaves' ?